# Поиск дат в формате dd-MM-yyyy с 1900 по 2019 с помощью регулярных выражений в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

`pattern` — это шаблон поиска регулярного выражения, в моем случае шаблон поиска даты. Как видим `result[1] = '65-58-3015'` не является датой. Что нужно добавить в шаблон, чтобы искало только те даты, в который день принимает значения 1-31, месяц 1-12 и год 1900-2019?

```
import re
string = '34-3456 / 12-05-2007 / 65-58-3015 / 56-4532 / 11-11-2011 / 67-8945 / 12-01-2009'
pattern = r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}'

result = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(result)

> ['12-05-2007', '65-58-3015', '11-11-2011', '12-01-2009']
```

Comment: `pattern = r'(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:[0-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'`?

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Тут еще загвоздка в том, что даты имеют вид 12-01-2009 вместо 12-1-2009. Я добавил нули в нужные места: `pattern = r'(?<!\d)(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'`

Comment: Лучше `r'(?<!\d)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'`. Нули необязательные, и месяц не может быть нулевым.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
r'(?<!\d)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/YJvt3n/2).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\d)` - сразу слева не должно быть цифры
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - целые числа от 1 до 31 (перед числами от 1 до 9 может быть необязательный 0)
- `-` - дефис
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - целые числа от 1 до 12 (перед числами от 1 до 9 может быть необязательный 0)
- `-` - дефис
- `(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])` - целые числа от 1900 до 2019
- `(?!\d)` - сразу справа не должно быть цифры

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/koXNd7):

```
import re
string = '34-3456 / 12-05-2007 / 65-58-3015 / 56-4532 / 11-11-2011 / 67-8945 / 12-01-2009'
pattern = r'(?<!\d)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'
result = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(result)
```